# How to Detect Backspace character in TextInput with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to detect typed character is the backspace/delete

```
if (e.nativeEvent.key === 'Backspace')
```

tried this but not working

Answer (score 33, accepted):

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onkeypress

```
<TextInput
  onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
    if (nativeEvent.key === 'Backspace') {
      ...doTheMagic();...
    }
  }}
/>
```

**Live example:** https://snack.expo.io/@zvona/backspace

Comment: suppose i want to prevent the backspace from deleting text, how can it be done?

Comment: @GauravRoy onChangeText check for if the pressed character is backspace, then return null